# Problemas para criar uma chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql

Pessoal preciso criar um relacionamento entre a tabela atendimento e a tabela categoria, mas toda vez que eu tento ele da o erro 1215 cannot add foreign key. O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Ambas as tabelas estão vazias.

```
CREATE TABLE `atendimentos` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cliente_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`categoria_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`contato` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

e esta é tabela de categorias:

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`parent_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`slug` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`label` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`icon` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `categorias_slug_unique` (`slug`),
KEY `categorias_parent_id_foreign` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: João voce está tentando relacionar uma FK com a própria tabela?((KEY `fk_cliente` (`cliente_id`)))

Comment: @ClaytonTosatti não. Estou tentando relacionar o atendimentos.categoria_id com categorias.id.

Comment: já experimentou não colocar DEFAULT "1" para categoria_id?

Comment: você quer criar o relacionamento já no create table? Ou editar e adicionar depois?

Comment: As tabelas já estão criadas então tem que ser no depois. Mas as tabelas ainda não tem conteúdos.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o código pra criar a foreign key. Lembre-se da ordem:

Primeiro o CREATE TABLE da tabela categoria, e depois atendimentos.

```
CREATE TABLE `atendimentos` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cliente_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`categoria_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`contato` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
CONSTRAINT FK_Atendimento_Categoria FOREIGN KEY (categoria_id)
REFERENCES categorias(id)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Caso as tabelas já estejam criadas e queira adicionar depois:

```
ALTER TABLE atendimentos
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Atendimento_Categoria
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES categorias(id);
```

Edit: Como informou e fez como acima, veja se o problema não está no default. Primeiro faça isso:

```
ALTER TABLE atendimentos
ALTER COLUMN id DROP DEFAULT;

 ALTER TABLE atendimentos
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Atendimento_Categoria
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES categorias(id);
```

Comment: Foi exatamente isto que eu estou fazendo so que da o erro. 
SQL]ALTER TABLE atendimentos
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Atendimento_Categoria
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES categorias(id);
[Err] 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Veja minha edição mostrando como reomver o default.

Answer (score 0):

Achei o erro. A pessoa que criou a tabela Categoria colocou o ID com unsigned ai não vai mesmo. Tirei o unsigned e tudo certo. Muito obrigado a todos.